# Power Automate Workflow - Custom Responses – Wait for all responses

Tags: power-automate

I need to create a Power Automate workflow.
I have three approvers. Each of them should approve or reject the document. If any two of them approve the document, the final decision should be "Approved". How do I get the result "Approved" at the end?
If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

[image]